# Why can't a "Class" variable be passed to instanceof?

Tags: java, class, instanceof

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
    public boolean isOf(Class clazz, Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof clazz){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Why I can't pass a class variable to `instanceof`?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator works on reference types, like `Integer`, and not on objects, like `new Integer(213)`. You probably want something like

```
clazz.isInstance(obj)
```

---

Side note: your code will be more concise if you write

```
public boolean isOf(Class clazz, Object obj){
    return clazz.isInstance(obj)
}
```

Not really sure if you need a method anymore ,though.

Comment: I know the code is totally useless, I just want to demonstrate my confusion:)

Comment: `Integer` is **not** a class literal. `Integer.class` would be a class literal (see § 15.8.2 of the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2). The `instanceof` operator takes a "ReferenceType" (a.k.a a type name) as specified § 15.20.2 of the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2

Comment: I'd use `clazz.isInstance(obj)` since the object's already been supplied.

Answer (score 18):

`instanceof` can be used only with explicit class names (stated at compile time). In order to do a *runtime* check, you should do:

```
clazz.isInstance(obj)
```

This has a small advantage over `clazz.isAssignableFrom(..)` since it deals with the case `obj == null` better.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, you cannot pass a class variable to `instanceof` because a class variable references an instance of an *Object*, while the right hand of `instanceof` has to be a *type*. That is, `instanceof` does not mean "y is an instance of Object x", it means "y is an instance of type X". In case you don't know the difference between an Object and a type, consider:

`Object o = new Object();`

Here, the type is `Object`, and `o` is a reference to the instance of the Object with that type. Thus:

`if(o instanceof Object)`

is valid but

`if(o instanceof o)`

is not because `o` on the right hand side is an Object, not a type.

More specific to your case, a class instance is not a type, it is an *Object* (which is created for you by the JVM). In your method, `Class` is a type, but `clazz` is an Object (well, a reference to an Object)

What you need is an way to compare an Object to a Class Object. It turns out that this is popular so this is provided to you as a method of the Class Object: `isInstance()`.

Here is the Java Doc for isInstance, which explains this better:

> `public boolean isInstance(Object obj)`
>
> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the
>   object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic
>   equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. The method
>   returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be
>   cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without
>   raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.
>
> Specifically, if this Class object represents a declared class, this
>   method returns true if the specified Object argument is an instance of
>   the represented class (or of any of its subclasses); it returns false
>   otherwise. If this Class object represents an array class, this method
>   returns true if the specified Object argument can be converted to an
>   object of the array class by an identity conversion or by a widening
>   reference conversion; it returns false otherwise. If this Class object
>   represents an interface, this method returns true if the class or any
>   superclass of the specified Object argument implements this interface;
>   it returns false otherwise. If this Class object represents a
>   primitive type, this method returns false.
>
> **Parameters:** obj - the object to check
>   **Returns:** true if obj is an instance of this class
>   **Since:** JDK1.1

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `instanceof` requires that the operand on the right is an actual class (e.g. `obj instanceof Object` or `obj instanceof Integer`) and not a variable of type `Class`. Secondly, you have made a fairly common newbie mistake that you really should not do... the following pattern:

```
if ( conditional_expression ){
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
```

The above can be refactored into:

```
return conditional_expression;
```

You should always perform that refactoring, as it eliminates a redundant if...else statement. Similarly, the expression `return conditional_expression ? true : false;` is refactorable to the same result.

Comment: That is no mistake. Maybe clumsy but total okay. Maybe you want additional code before returning in the foreseeable future...