# Java instanceof with class name

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I am just curious to ask this, maybe it is quite meaningless.

When we are using instanceof in java, like:

```
if (a instanceof Parent){ //"Parent" here is a parent class of "a"
}
```

why we can't use like below:

```
if (a instanceof Parent.class){
}
```

Does the second 'instanceof' make more sense from the view of strict programming? What is the difference between "Parent" and "Parent.class"?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590640/why-cant-a-class-variable-be-passed-to-instanceof

Comment: Note: for the second approach, `Parent.class.isInstance(a)` would be the appropriate check.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is the difference between "Parent" and "Parent.class"?

The latter is a *class literal* - a way of accessing an object of type `Class<Parent>`.

The former is just the name of a class, which is used in various situations - when calling static methods, constructors, casting etc.

> Does the second 'instanceof' make more sense from the view of strict programming?

Well not as the language is defined - `instanceof` *only* works with the name of a type, *never* an expression. If you could write

```
if (a instanceof Parent.class)
```

then I'd *expect* you do be able to write:

```
Class<?> clazz = Parent.class;
if (a instanceof clazz)
```

... and that's just not the way it works. On the other hand, there *is* the `Class.isInstance` method which you can call if you want.

What do you mean by "the view of strict programming" in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`Parent` is a class, so the second example doesn't make more sense that the first. You're asking if the instance is an instance of the class, `a instanceof Parent` is a pretty direct expression of that.

`Parent.class` is an *instance* of `Class`, so even if the second example compiled (it doesn't, the right-hand of `instanceof` can't itself be an instance), it wouldn't check what you want it to check. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Parent` is the name of a type.  `Parent.class` is essentially a static variable that refers to an object (specifically, an instance of `Class`).  You want to ask whether `a` is an instance of the `Parent` type, not whether it's an instance of an object that is itself an instance of some other type (named `Class`).

Answer (score 0):

The static `Parent.class` member is actually an object. You could assign it to a variable of type `Object` or type `Class` if you wanted to:

```
Object o = Parent.class;
Class c = Parent.class;
```

`Parent` on the other hand isn't an object or a variable: it is a [Type Name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.5), as per the Java spec.

If you could do this...

```
a instanceof Parent.class
```

Since `Parent.class` is an *object* then you could feasibly could also do this:

```
Cat myCat = new DomesticLonghair();
a instanceof myCat;
```

... which is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not silly, as suggested above!

Between classes the subclass relation is defined by method
`Class<?>.isAssignableFrom()`

```
if (Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass()))
{
    // a is instance of Parent or subclass
}
```