# How to store a class name in any variable and use it with instanceof operator

Tags: java, instanceof, classname

```
  // store the class name in varibale className
    DataType className = ValueOfclassName;
    if(a instanceof className)
            {
                System.out.println("This is instance");
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java instanceof with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873933/java-instanceof-with-class-name)

Answer (score 1):

Well,`instanceof` is about `Class`, but class name is a `String`. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526817/4210091).

Anyway, can this answer to your question?

```
A i = new A();
if (i instanceof A) {

}
```

if you want a String rapresentation of a class you can use:

```
A.class.getName()
```