# Checking method template parameter type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method:

```java
<T> String getBeanStrategyName(Store baseStoreModel, T clazz) {
    if (clazz instanceof PointsStrategy) {
        return baseStoreModel.getPointsStrategy();
    } else if (clazz instanceof RedemptionStrategy) {
        return baseStoreModel.getRedemptionStrategy();
    } else {
        return baseStoreModel.getPointsStrategy();
    }
}
```

However when I call the method like this `getBeanStrategyName(store,PointsStrategy.class)`, the check `clazz instanceof PointsStrategy` returns false. I need somehow to check the passsed type  and based on it return particular strategy

Comment: Object of type `PointsStrategy` is not the same as `PointsStrategy.class`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java instanceof with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873933/java-instanceof-with-class-name)

Answer (score 1):

`PointsStrategy.class` is of type `java.lang.Class`, not `PointsStrategy` so it rightfully returns `false`.

You can check it using

```
clazz.equals(PointsStrategy.class)
```

and btw it's better to declare the parameter as `Class<?>` to have a clearer contract,

```
String getBeanStrategyName(Store baseStoreModel, Class<?> clazz)
```

Comment: Yes, or `<T extends Strategy> String getBeanStrategyName(Store baseStoreModel, Class<T> clazz)`

Comment: or simpler `String getBeanStrategyName(Store baseStoreModel, Class<? extends Strategy> clazz)`